# C++ pointers and heap deallocation

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm just getting to grips with C++ heap memory management (coming from a JS / C# GC managed world) and am wondering why this works(!):

This:

```
 for (int i{5}; i > 0; --i)
    {
        keepMakingMemoryLeak();
    }
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

Calls this:

```
void keepMakingMemoryLeak()
{
    std::vector<std::string>* ptrToMyArray = new std::vector<std::string>;

    ptrToMyArray->push_back("John");
    ptrToMyArray->push_back("Jane");
    ptrToMyArray->push_back("Jack");

    remmotelyModifVector(ptrToMyArray);


    std::cout << "The array is: \n "; std::cout.flush();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ptrToMyArray->size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "index: \t" << i << " is \t" << ptrToMyArray->at(i) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Capacity is now" << ptrToMyArray->capacity() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size is now" << ptrToMyArray->size() << "\n";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ptrToMyArray->size(); i++)
    {
        if (ptrToMyArray->at(i) == "") {
            std::cout << "index: \t" << i << " exists \t" << " but is empty (zero length string) \n";
        }
    }

    delete ptrToMyArray;
}


void remmotelyModifVector(std::vector<std::string>* someArray)
{
    someArray->at(1).erase();
    someArray->shrink_to_fit();

}
```

The above does what you think it does - it calls `keepMakingMemoryLeak()` 4 times, which each time allocates an `std::vector` to the heap, assigns some basic strings, passes the pointer to another function, which nukes index[1], and control then returns to the caller `keepMakingMemoryLeak()` to dump the contents of the vector to `cout`, which works as expected. (index 1 now == zero length string? or null?). Finally, `keepMakingMemoryLeak()` calls `delete ptrToMyArray;` and the loop repeats.

Using MS memory leak `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` I get a report of no leaks - which is not what I was expecting. Surely just deleting the pointer to the vector means the vector itself (and it's `std::string` elements?) is still on the heap?

If I comment out `delete ptrToMyArray;` then I **do** get memory leak reports:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{308} normal block at 0x01153540, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <T.      > 54 2E 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{307} normal block at 0x0114E3F0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <8.      > 38 2E 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{306} normal block at 0x0114F5E0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <p.      > 70 2E 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{305} normal block at 0x01152E38, 84 bytes long.
 Data: <    John        > F0 E3 14 01 4A 6F 68 6E 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC 
{296} normal block at 0x0114F3B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ,      > E8 2C 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{295} normal block at 0x01152CE8, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    8.   .   .  > B0 F3 14 01 38 2E 15 01 8C 2E 15 01 8C 2E 15 01 
{282} normal block at 0x0114F848, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <l-      > 6C 2D 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{281} normal block at 0x0114F618, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <P-      > 50 2D 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{280} normal block at 0x0114F538, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < -      > 88 2D 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{279} normal block at 0x01152D50, 84 bytes long.
 Data: <    John        > 18 F6 14 01 4A 6F 68 6E 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC 
{270} normal block at 0x0114F298, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ,      > 00 2C 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{269} normal block at 0x01152C00, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    P-   -   -  > 98 F2 14 01 50 2D 15 01 A4 2D 15 01 A4 2D 15 01 
{256} normal block at 0x0114F260, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ,      > 84 2C 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{255} normal block at 0x0114F570, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <h,      > 68 2C 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{254} normal block at 0x0114F3E8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ,      > A0 2C 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{253} normal block at 0x01152C68, 84 bytes long.
 Data: <p   John        > 70 F5 14 01 4A 6F 68 6E 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC 
{244} normal block at 0x0114F1F0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < '      > 10 27 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{243} normal block at 0x01152710, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    h,   ,   ,  > F0 F1 14 01 68 2C 15 01 BC 2C 15 01 BC 2C 15 01 
{230} normal block at 0x0114F308, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < '      > 94 27 15 01 00 00 00 00 
{229} normal block at 0x0114F768, 8 bytes long.
```

Which is weird. I'm obviously missing something here, but researching this doesn't tell me why just blindly deleting the pointer works OK.

Cheers,
JSC

Comment: But `delete ptrToMyArray` deletes the vector object you allocated with `new`, why should it leak?

Comment: I would recommend that you simply not use `new`/`delete`, and do everything via RAII or safe container or smart pointer classes. End users should not manually manage memory. But that said, why do you think that `delete` would 'only delete the pointer' and not deallocate what it points to? What would 'only deleting a pointer' even mean?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding between variables, pointers, and objects. You can create an object with `new` and as a result you get a pointer to that object. You can assign that pointer to a variable. The variable itself and its storage is managed by the compiler. When you `delete` you don't delete the variable, you delete the object it points to.

Comment: You `delete` what you `new`ed -> no leaks, you don't `delete` -> leaks. Ok, what is not clear about that? What is your question? And please note that in your code there is no reason to allocate anything manually. The way you do it is not exception safe and should be avoided at all costs. C++ mangages all memory for you automatically if you just let it do so. Don't use raw `new` and `delete`

Comment: It would be a leak if the strings in the vector where as pointers `std::string*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I assumed (wrongly) that deleting the pointer does *exactly* just that - delete the pointer, not necessarily the object it's pointing to. The point on RAII taken, thanks - I'm just learning how the language works at a fundamental level at the moment - I've clearly a long way to go!

Comment: @JSC in general, a memory leak is a `new` without a corresponding `delete`.  In modern C++, one can usually code without using either.

Comment: @JSC manually managing memory when there is no need to is fundamentally wrong ;). It has to be said this clear, because when done wrong it is a nightmare, if done right it works like a charm

Comment: @JSC `delete ptr;` *only* deletes what the pointer points to (and anything that object's destructor also `delete`s, recursively). It doesn't delete the pointer itself. The pointer still exists but has an invalid pointer value (it doesn't point to anything). You can still use it by making it point to an object again (ex. `ptr = *obj;`). Otherwise, this would be problematic as ultimately you eventually need to use a pointer that was not dynamically allocated, which cannot be `delete`d.

Comment: `erase()` on an `std::string` causes it to become an empty string. The `std::string` still exists. It doesn't get removed from the owning container. The only way to remove an object from an `std::vector` is through `std::vector` member functions. Since you didn't call `erase` or `clear` or anything like that on the `std::vector` it still contains the same number of elements.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` is a non-binding call that can be used to release excess memory. It does not compact or otherwise refresh the seeuence the `std::vector` represents. It seems you may be under the impression that it is used to eliminate "dead" elements of the vector and remove "empty" slots. This is not the case, there is no such thing as an empty spot in C++ sequence container. If you can define a value that represents a "dead" element is (for example, if you decide null pointers need to be removed), you can compact the container with a combination of `std::remove_if` and `std::vector::erase`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks - I think I realised that after posting my code. I'm calling erase() on the object at index[1] in the container (vector), which happens to be (in this case) a string, so sure enough, the std::string itself is still there (capacity & size of the vector doesn't change). It hasn't touched the sequence in the vector itself and therefore shrink will have no effect....to actually make the vector wipe out objects, I need to call a member / method on the vector itself

Comment: @idclev463035818  and Drew Dormann. Yup - I'm torturing myself by using new / delete ;-) but I find it the best way to learn something new (break it / find out why it isn't doing what I thought it might...). I suspect production code doesn't go near patterns of code like the one I've posted but once I "get it", I'll be able to move to RAII etc and understand *why* I don't need new / delete in most situations.

Comment: i suggest you to implement a simple smart pointer. It isnt too hard, you will learn something that is useful also for later, and nobody will complain for using `new` and `delete` ;)